# Android Things Audio I2S not available

Tags: linux, android-things

I'm trying to play sound through I2S with Android Things, but keep getting

```
E/audio_hw_hikey: cannot open pcm_out driver: cannot open device '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0p': No such file or directory 48000 2 0
```

I've checked the audio devices using `adb ls /dev/snd` and the device does exist

```
000041ed 00000078 5db48f0c .
000041ed 00000500 00000008 ..
000021b0 00000000 00000002 pcmC0D1p
000021b0 00000000 00000002 controlC0
000021b0 00000000 00000002 pcmC0D0p
000021b0 00000000 00000002 timer
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to directly open the I2S bus using a path? That won't work. Instead, you use the AudioTrack API and [set the preferred device](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant#audio-configuration) which will pipe it to the I2S channel.

```
audioInputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_INPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);
audioOutputDevice = findAudioDevice(AudioManager.GET_DEVICES_OUTPUTS, AudioDeviceInfo.TYPE_BUS);
```

The linked sample [includes some code](https://github.com/androidthings/sample-googleassistant/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/androidthings/assistant/AssistantActivity.java#L311) on how to do it.